# NumPy ndarray are plotted differently than equivalent lists?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I expected "b" to be plotted the same way as "a", but it's not:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

figure, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 1)

a = [[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]]
b = np.array(object = a)

axes[0].hist(x = a, bins = np.arange(start = 0, stop = 5, step = 1), density = True)
axes[1].hist(x = b, bins = np.arange(start = 0, stop = 5, step = 1), density = True)

figure.show()
```

[image]

Why?

Comment: Often in `numpy`, and to a less extent in `matplotlib`, lists converted to arrays, e.g. `np.asarray(alist)`.  But check the docs if there's any question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist` [just does that](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist.html). It's weird.

> Multiple data can be provided via x as a list of datasets of potentially different length ([x0, x1, ...]), or as a 2-D ndarray in which each column is a dataset. **Note that the ndarray form is transposed relative to the list form.**

If you pass a list of datasets, each row is a dataset. If you pass a 2D array, each column is a dataset.

Comment: oh wow, why did they design it like that?  Such inconsistency considering if you pass 1-D versions of both, they behave the same way, so you'll expect the same behaviour at higher dimensions but it's not.